# How to remove html between XML elements

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

Forgive me with my lack of coding knowledge.

I am trying to remove the html in between 2 common elements in an XML feed. I am using notepad++

Here is an example of the XML:

```
<title><![CDATA[example]]></title>
<description><![CDATA[&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Genuine Simplicity A Bags are No Longer Sold in Packs of 3. These Paper Bags Are Only Sold in Quantities of 6. &lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;a title=&quot;Simplicity A Bags 6 Pack&quot; href=&quot;https://www.vacuumcleanermarket.com/simplicity-vacuum-bags-type-a-6-series-s6-6.html&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;Please Click Here to Purchase These Bags in a 6 Pack&lt;/a&gt;.&nbsp;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Genuine Simplicity type A 2-ply]]></description>
<link><![CDATA[example.com]]></link>
<g:image_link>example</g:image_link>
<g:condition>new</g:condition>
<g:price>5.99 USD</g:price>
<g:shipping>
    <g:country>US</g:country>
    </g:shipping>
    <g:shipping_price_value>6.95</g:shipping_price_value>
    <g:shipping_price_currency>USD</g:shipping_price_currency>
<g:custom_label_0><![CDATA[simplicity bags and parts]]></g:custom_label_0>
<g:custom_label_1></g:custom_label_1>
<g:custom_label_2></g:custom_label_2>
<g:availability><![CDATA[Out of Stock]]></g:availability>
<g:google_product_category></g:google_product_category>
<g:identifier_exists>TRUE</g:identifier_exists>
<g:product_type></g:product_type>
<g:sale_price>5.99 USD</g:sale_price>
<g:sale_price_effective_date>2013-03-01T00:00+00:00/2038-01-01T00:00+00:00</g:sale_price_effective_date>
<g:brand><![CDATA[Simplicity]]></g:brand>
<g:gtin></g:gtin>
</item><item><g:id><![CDATA[Sim-005]]></g:id>
```

There are over 1200 listings like this in the XML feed.

I am trying to remove the non-text and punctuation between and URL's: "

Also bloat html in between those 2 elements is not always the same it differs per listing.

Comment: How about using an XML parser, then you get the text of the `description` element such as `&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Genuine Simplicity A Bags are ... &lt;p&gt;Genuine Simplicity type A 2-ply`. From there you can entity decode the text to get the HTML, from which you can get the plain text.

Comment: You can however use regex to clean up the text if you can live with some unresolved corner cases. To help you please let us know which XML elements you want to clean up, and what the expected output looks like. Also, show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please clarify so that we can help you